# Displaying a Specific Value If Specific Criteria Are Met Across a Range

Tags: excel

Seems like a simple thing to do but cannot for the life of me figure out the right formula:

I want I5 to display 0 when I1-4 are NO and I want I5 to display .5 ONLY when all rows are YES.

[Excel Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUD2V.jpg)

Comment: So right now you've only provided examples for when they are either all no, or all yes.  What if some are no and some are yes?  Is there a scale?  Like is .1 a possible output?

Comment: Sorry, the only two possible values I want are 0: if any of them say NO, or .5: if all are YES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `NO` and `YES` are the only options use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I1:I4,"NO"),0,.5)
```

If the values can be other than `NO` and `YES` then use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I1:I4,"YES")=4,.5,0)
```

Comment: @RADominusRex please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.